# How Can I Load localhost:3000 in Chrome On Issuing A "rails s" Command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

My workflow looks like this:

1. `$>mate .`
2. Edit stuff using textmate
3. Go to command line to run `$>rails s`
4. Go to Chrome to click a bookmark that loads localhost:3000
5. View the app
6. Load text mate to fix/revise
7. Back to command line to git
8. Repeat

Is it possible to rig step 3 so that it will also load a new tab with localhost:3000 in it? One less click, saved many times.

Comment: Gareth, I've updated each issue to accept the answer I used. I should have been aware of this feature but missed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using TextMate I'll assume you're on a Mac.

Two things you can do.

1. Setup Phusion Passenger on Apache (Mac OS X already has apache) so you save yourself the rails s. You can find tutorials on this at many location. But basically you follow the [instructions from the Passenger website](http://www.modrails.com/install.html) and then [install the Passenger PreferencePane](http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane) to make your life easier. To do this you'll need the XCode installed.
2. Start the rails server in the background then calling open to open the URL

   ```
   #!/bin/bash  
   #  
   # save this in script/start.sh  
   # don't forget to do chmod +x script/start.sh  
   rails s &  
   sleep 4
   open http://localhost:3000
   ```

Comment: Added links to the Passenger PrefPane as suggested by John.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the recommendation for Passenger above, I'd also add that you can install the "Passenger Pref Pane" that will let you easily add projects and set their environments (production/development).

Passenger + Passenger Pref Pane will completely eliminate the need for rails -s, with minimal fussing on the Apache config files.

I think Textmate also allows you to do some scripting that might even get you to be able to launch and open the url in Chrome on save, but I haven't ventured into that area of Textmate yet, and it would probably take more work than just hitting refresh after the save.

Comment: Just found something on the Textmate actions here http://wiki.macromates.com/textmate/show/Howtos.html . The "Reload in Browsers" section might get you started, and I might have to try it as well. Been meaning to explore the scripting functions in Textmate.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding some code, you could put this in your config/application.rb:

```
config.after_initialize do
  if Rails.env == 'development'
    system('open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app http://localhost:3000') 
  end
end
```

That will open a new tab each time though and if this is a multi-person project, you may get complaints.

Another option would be to look at [live-reload](https://github.com/mockko/livereload) to get the tab to refresh when a file changes. Even without Passenger, on Rails 3 I rarely have to restart the server, so just reloading the tab might make more sense.

Comment: Or, use your suggestion, but instead of `if Rails.env == 'development'` use something like `if ENV['OPEN_UP'].present`. Then just use `OPEN_UP=t rails s`